# How to call different member functions using template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, c++20

I am trying to call a variable number of member functions of a struct

caller.cpp

```
//JUST BLINDLY ITERATING
MyStruct s;

for( member_function : s.member_functions) //HOW TO DO THIS?
{
    member_function();
}
```

structure.cpp

```
MyStruct
{
    //CAN HAVE N NUMBER OF MEMBER FUNCTIONS
    float a();
    void b(int);
    char c(float, int);
}
```

I think I can maybe use a vector to store pointer to the functions, but I dont want to do that. I dont want to add to vector everytime I create a new member function.

Is it possible to do some template metaprogramming to achieve this?

Comment: c++ does not have reflection, so no it's not possible. Also, even if you manually manage a vector of pointers - your methods seem to have different parameters. So how do you intend to call them ?

Comment: C++ doesn't have (runtime) reflection (and limited introspection at compile time, meta programming). So it is not possible. The interesting question is : "What" are you trying to do?

Comment: @wohlstad You are right. So using vector is also out of window.

Comment: Suggest changing your design, and checking how to use the template to implement the "Chain of Responsibility".

Comment: @PepijnKramer  I want to serialize my entites in ECS, for which I need to get values of each component (eg: rotation, translation etc). I can call each member functions for a component but I was thinking if there is a better way like iterate each member function rather than calling then manually.

Comment: "//HAS NO IDEA WHAT ARE THE MEMBER FUNCTIONS" is not true. You can only create an object when you know the class definition

Comment: make the entities have 1 member function `serialize`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number can you kindly elaborate on what should `serialize` do?

Comment: @Rogmier Whatever you'd be doing with the data from the components if you had magically extracted it in `Entity::serialize`

Comment: i don't know, what would you do with the result of calling `member_function();` ?

Comment: you could make each `MyStruct` hold a container of its member functions that can be iterated, but as others explained this would be of little help, because eventually you want to call them and then you do need to know its parameters. Its a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what you think would be a viable solution to your original problem is none. You should rather tell us about your originial problem

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ simply doesn't work this way, on a fundamental level.